# How to get category object from category name

Tags: php, wordpress

how do I get category object from category name? I can't seem to find a function that does that. if the category name is "my category". I tried running:

```
get_category('my category);
```

but it just returns 0.

Comment: I want get_category_by_name

Comment: `$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    echo $term->name;` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_term_by` function.

```
$category = get_term_by('name', 'my category', 'category')
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by